# monitoring unused sites (not site collections)

Tags: 2007, monitoring

I have a really large SharePoint 2007 environment with lots of site collections and each site collection has a number of subsites. I would like to monitor whether these subsites are used. I know there are many reporting tools but I don't want to look at a report manually. I would like to receive an e-mail alert (for example) once a week which shows me the unused subsites so I can contact the owners of these sites. Are there any third party tools that can do this for me? If not, is there a way to implement this with code without using timer jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You would need either a C# application or a PowerShell script that would run as a scheduled task. The important thing is how to access each `SPWeb` in the site collection. I don't know enough about your requirements or your environment to make a guess about this. You might want to do it recursively for every site and sub-site in each site collection (something that could really slow down a server) or you might not. I'll leave that up to you. Don't forget to dispose of your web objects!

The code in PowerShell would look something like this:

```
[void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint.domain.com/")

foreach($web in $site.RootWeb.Webs)
{
    if($web.LastItemModifiedDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))
    {
        #Do stuff here to send your email
    }
}
$site.Dispose()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.lastitemmodifieddate(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: May want to add a throttle like "Start-Sleep -s 1" inside the foreach loop... ;)